# How to determine gain of this op-amp setup

Tags: single-supply-op-amp, operational-amplifier

This circuitry is present to form current signal (from current transducer - LEM) to voltage signal (to be feed to the ACD).
It doesn't represent typical setup of non-inverting opamp (lack of the resistor from inverting input to 0V).

How is the gain in this setup calculated?

[image: CurrentInput]

Comment: Looks like a buffer to me. Gain=1 at DC (of the op-amp configuration only, that is)

Comment: This looks fairly easy to simulate. Do you use a simulator?

Comment: I haven't in this case. But as this seems to be just a buffer, I will do and see how the voltage divider values influences it.